# Add data from Map to dynamically created Views

Tags: java, android, android-studio, view, hashmap

I have method **CreateView**, which dynamically creates View and fill them with data from SharedPrefernces file.

First *for* **(File loadFile : loadFiles)** work correctly. It fills data in  fields in created View that 100% are in the file SharedPrefernces.

Second *for* **(Map.Entry entry : usersPresets.getAll().entrySet())**. It fills data in created Views, but not the fact that they are in SharedPrefences file. And here I got problem.

```
public void CreateView(File[] loadFiles) {
        if (presetsStorage.exists()) {
            for (File loadFile : loadFiles) {
                //noinspection SpellCheckingInspection
                if (!loadFile.getName().contains("userpreset_")) {
                    //noinspection UnnecessaryContinue
                    continue;
                } else {
                    if (loadFile.isFile()) {
                        String presetsName = loadFile.getName();
                        presetsName = presetsName.substring(0, presetsName.length() - 4);
                        usersPresets = getSharedPreferences(presetsName, MODE_PRIVATE);
                        presetsContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.presetsContainer);

                        View userPresetsView = getLayoutInflater()
                                .inflate(R.layout.preset_fragment, presetsContainer, false);
                        userPresetsView.findViewById(R.id.presetFragMenubtn)
                                .setOnClickListener(viewClickListener);

                        ((CircularSeekBar) userPresetsView.findViewById(R.id.presetFragA)).
                                setProgress(usersPresets.getInt("a", 0));
                        ((CircularSeekBar) userPresetsView.findViewById(R.id.presetFragB)).
                                setProgress(usersPresets.getInt("b", 0));
                        ((CircularSeekBar) userPresetsView.findViewById(R.id.presetFragC)).
                                setProgress(usersPresets.getInt("c", 0));

                        TextView presetFragName = (TextView) userPresetsView
                                .findViewById(R.id.userPresetName);
                        presetFragName.setText(presetsName);
                        presetFragName.setOnClickListener(viewClickListener2);

                        presetsContainer.addView(userPresetsView);
                        presetFragName.setText(presetsName.substring(11));

                        //HERE I HAVE A PROBLEM
                        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : usersPresets.getAll().entrySet()) {
                            if (arr.contains(entry.getKey())) {
                                // noinspection UnnecessaryContinue
                                continue;
                            } else {
                                CardView flavor_cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.flavor_cardView);
                                final View usersFlavorsPreset = getLayoutInflater()
                                        .inflate(R.layout.preset_userflavor_fragment, flavor_cardView, false);
                                ((TextView) usersFlavorsPreset.findViewById(R.id.tvUserFlavorPresetName))
                                        .setText(entry.getKey());
                                ((TextView) usersFlavorsPreset.findViewById(R.id.tvUserFlavorPresetValue)).
                                        setText(String.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
                                flavor_cardView.addView(usersFlavorsPreset);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I need that would, at presence of this data, created a new row, depending on the amount of data in the SharedPrefernces. Now, it works, but creates only one row and the values rewrites and displays only the data that were in the last iteration of the passage of second *for*.

Screenshots, where I tried to explain the problem:

View - [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDkBf.jpg)

Content of aaa.xml - [screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkH85.jpg)

Content of test.xml - [screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/px2c5.jpg)

Tell me please, where I need to place *for* that would have the values not overwritten in the same location.
I hope that explained at least a little understandable. If you do not know - I will try to describe the problem again.

**UPDATE**: I added to the CardView the LinearLayout, and all the elements are now displayed in one place. So another question - how to place them in the right box?

```
for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : usersPresets.getAll().entrySet()) {
                            if (arr.contains(entry.getKey())) {
                                // noinspection UnnecessaryContinue
                                continue;
                            } else {
                                LinearLayout flavor_linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.flavor_linear);
                                final View usersFlavorsPreset = getLayoutInflater().
                                        inflate(R.layout.preset_userflavor_fragment, flavor_linear, false);
                                ((TextView) usersFlavorsPreset.
                                        findViewById(R.id.tvUserFlavorPresetName)).setText(entry.getKey());
                                ((TextView) usersFlavorsPreset.
                                        findViewById(R.id.tvUserFlavorPresetValue)).setText(String.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
                                flavor_linear.addView(usersFlavorsPreset);
                            }
                        }
```

[image]